# Sort dictionary by the INT value of the value

Tags: python, sorting, dictionary

There are many posts here about sorting dictionaries in Python so I was careful to read them and hope this is not a duplicate:

I'm using a dictionary to hold words as keys and the occurrence of the word as value. This leads to a dictionary that could be like:

```
John 1
Robert 5
Susie 15
Alex 6
```

I want to sort them by occurrence (the 'value')

```
John 1
Robert 5
Alex 6
Susie 15
```

I'm using the following code to try to sort my dictionary like this:

```
sorted_words = sorted(words.iteritems(), key=itemgetter(1))
```

However this returns a sorted list of tuples that looks like this:

```
John 1
Susie 15
Robert 5
Alex 6
```

You can see the problem is that with the above code the values are sorted "alphabetically", so 15 follows 1, even though mathematically 15 > 5 and 6 and so should be last.

How can I fix the code to treat the values as INTs and not strings

Comment: What are the values stored as?  `str` or `int`?

Comment: @squiguy just tried it, it's not solving the problem

Comment: Yes, because they are being sorted in a lexicographic order by their string value now.

Comment: @Juicy yes. or `key=lambda x: int(x[1])`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to convert to values to integers in your key expression. Use

```
sorted_words = sorted(words.iteritems(), key=lambda x: int(x[1]))
```

It may be tempting to try something like `key=int(itemgetter(1))`, but this will not work since the key parameter is expecting a function.

Comment: The first version won't work. The second is fine, I just realized that it's the same as my answer

Comment: This isnt compatible with python3 - would be nice to update this. 


just swap out itemitems() with items()

Answer (score 4):

python3:

```
sorted_words=sorted(words.items(),key=lambda item: int(item[1]))
```

Answer (score 2):

If you're looking for words sorted by occurrence you really want to be using a `Counter`, which is basically a prebuilt histogram that will handle all of this for you, and even let you call the function `most_common` to get the most common elements from that dictionary.

```
from colletions import Counter

string = "There there are some some words here here"
test = Counter(string.split())
>>> test.most_common(2)
[('some', 2), ('here', 2)]
```

If that doesn't fit your application for some reason, you can (as other have suggested), sort your dictionary as follows:

```
sorted_words = sorted(words.iteritems(), key=lambda value: float(value[1]))
```

But a `Counter` does seem to be a much closer fit for your application.

Answer (score 1):

For this sort of thing, I tend to do something like

```
sorted_pairs = sorted(words.iteritems(), key=lambda p: p[1])
```

The above assumes that the values in `words` are indeed numbers.  If this is not the case, then I'd do

```
sorted_pairs = sorted(words.iteritems(), key=lambda p: float(p[1]))
```

(The reason for using `float` instead of `int` in the last expression is simply generality: the code stays the same even if your values start including floating point numbers.)